# Find answer over own comment

Tags: support, comments

i've commented an answer on SO, but now i could not find the Question/Answer again. Is there a way, to see all my comments for finding the SO-Page?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes go to your profile and select Activity and then comments. Please see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630261/bendeg?tab=activity&sort=comments)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Yep, it's on your profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630261/bendeg?tab=activity&sort=comments).

Although the practicality of that is determined by how many posts you comment on, and how long ago it was.

Sometimes, and this may or may not be relevant, I find that notifications are a more efficient way of finding posts--again, completely dependent on how many replies you receive and how far back you're hoping to look.

Comment: Perfect, i did not look at 'activity' :)